# JSON parsing Arabic android

Tags: android, json, arabic

I've this code that reads album names from file written in php, and displays them as a ListView. The problem is that once I write the album name in Arabic, it displays as a "Null" in the list.

my php files:
album.php

```
include_once './data.php';
$albums = array();
looping through each album
foreach ($album_tracks as $album) {
$tmp = array();
$tmp["id"] = $album["id"];
$tmp["name"] = $album["album"];
$tmp["songs_count"] = count($album["songs"]);
// push album
array_push($albums, $tmp);
}
// printing json
echo json_encode($albums);
```

data.php

```
$album_tracks = array(
9 => array(
    "id" => 9,
    "album" => "No Angel",  // album name
    "songs" => array(
        array("id" => 1, "name" => "Here With Me", "duration" => "4:05")
    )
)
```

if you need my java code, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Put `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=sjis');`
in your php file.

Comment: I put it in my php files, and i even change the charset=UTF-8.. still not working

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing the encoding of the php file to UTF-8.